# Recommended open source workflow engine in java for non-business kind scenarios

Tags: java, open-source, workflow

My use case is not to model a business process workflow. I need a simple, easy to use and low learning curve workflow engine where I can model a simple workflow. I have a bunch of backend processes and each process needs to wait for the completion of previous process and also look at its status.

I see a whole bunch here but can't decide which one to use! 
http://java-source.net/open-source/workflow-engines

thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use [WSO2 Carbon Studio](http://wso2.com/products/carbon-studio/) to model the workflow using the BPEL editor, then deploy the artefact in [WSO2 BPS](http://wso2.com/products/business-process-server/) or [Apache ODE](http://ode.apache.org/).

You can use Eclipse Helios with WSO2 Carbon Studio 1.0.14

You can find a tutorial [here](http://wso2.org/library/tutorials/2011/04/using-carbon-studio-model-wsbpel-process-using-bpel-editor).

Also [this article](http://wso2.org/library/articles/writing-simple-ws-bpel-process-wso2-bps-apache-ode#invoke-partner-service) explains a similar workflow which you have mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Check out WSO2 Products

[image: http://wso2.org/library/bps]

[image]
<sub>(source: [wso2.org](http://wso2.org/sites/images/logos/brs_logo_h42.gif))</sub>

http://wso2.org/library/brs

http://wso2.org/library/bps

Answer (score 1):

The three most visible/active, in alphabetical order:

- http://www.activiti.org/
- http://www.bonitasoft.com
- http://www.jboss.org/jbpm

I'd suggest going through the tutorial/quickstart of each of them to get acquainted.

Answer (score 0):

[Imixs Workflow](http://www.imixs.org) is an open source Java Enterprise workflow engine. 
With the sub project [Imixs Workflow Script](http://www.imixs.org/script/) you have an easy way to start with a workflow application based on JavaScript and jQuery.